# Concise way to create new dictionary with specific property as key, from list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking to create a new dictionary from a list of dictionaries, with a specific property from those dictionaries as a new key.

Here is an example to better outline the concept:

**Original**

```
[
   {
      "id":"asdf1234",
      "firstname":"john",
      "lastname":"smith",
      "age":30
   },
   {
      "id":"sdfg2345",
      "firstname":"jane",
      "lastname":"doe",
      "age":25
   },
   {
      "id":"dfgh3456",
      "firstname":"billy",
      "lastname":"ericson",
      "age":35
   }
]
```

**Transformed**

```
{
   "asdf1234":{
      "firstname":"john",
      "lastname":"smith",
      "age":30
   },
   "sdfg2345":{
      "firstname":"jane",
      "lastname":"doe",
      "age":25
   },
   "dfgh3456":{
      "firstname":"billy",
      "lastname":"ericson",
      "age":35
   }
}
```

I understand this can be done using this ugly code, I'm looking for a more concise and elegant way to do so.

```py
transformed = {}

for i in range(len(data)):
    transformed[data[i]['id']] = data[i]
    del transformed[data[i]['id']]['id']

return transformed
```

Comment: The biggest problem with your code is `for i in range(len(data)):`, don't do that, loop over the list directdly, `for d in data: transformed[d.pop('id')] = d`

Comment: I agree it works, it just feels like there must be a more pythonic way to make the same transformation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using [Dictionary Comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), and the `pop()` method. Here's an example:

```py
return {item.pop('id'):item for item in data}
```

You would replace `id` with whatever property you would like to set as the key.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I'm glad we got that sorted! Python is filled with tricks like this

Answer (score 1):

```
dicts = [
   {
      "id":"asdf1234",
      "firstname":"john",
      "lastname":"smith",
      "age":30
   },
   {
      "id":"sdfg2345",
      "firstname":"jane",
      "lastname":"doe",
      "age":25
   },
   {
      "id":"dfgh3456",
      "firstname":"billy",
      "lastname":"ericson",
      "age":35
   }
]    

new_dicts = {d.pop('id'): d for d in dicts}
```